# scroll bar vertical on c++ builder

Tags: user-interface, scrollbar, c++builder

I´m doing a bit GUI, this has a `Form` with a `TMemo` with the property `ScrollBars` set to `ssVertical` but I would like that the vertical scroll only shows when necessary, at present it's always shown. How can I disable when not necessary and enable when necessary?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, TMemo's scrollbars do not work that way.  If they are enbled then they are always displayed, regardless of the content.  Switch to a TRichEdit instead.